# Unable to access database in Silverlight through WCF Services?

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I am creating a login page where username and password should be  checked from database.
I have a table **LoginTable** with *username* and *password*

My code is shown here

**WCF service - LoginService.cvs.cs**

```
public class LoginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public int ValidateUsers(string username, string password)
    {
        int count;
        string connection = ("Data Source=(localdb);Initial Catalog=smsdb;
        Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
        TrustServerCertificate=False");
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("[Login_Authentication]", conn);
        SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("@username", username);
        comm.Parameters.Add(para);
        SqlParameter para1 = new SqlParameter("@password", password);
        comm.Parameters.Add(para1);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        count = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
        return count;
        conn.Close();
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

and my **XAML.CS**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (uname.Text == "" && pass.Password == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Username and password");
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = new MyLoginService.LoginServiceClient();
            obj.ValidateUsersCompleted += new EventHandler
            <ValidateUsersCompletedEventArgs>(obj_ValidateUsersCompleted);
            obj.ValidateUsersAsync(uname.Text, pass.Password);
        }
    }
    public void obj_ValidateUsersCompleted
    (object sender, slwcftut.MyLoginService.ValidateUsersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully");
            }
            else if (e.Result <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am not getting any error or answer.

Comment: Did you try your service in test client? is it working?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't have WCF test client

Comment: What? It comes with Visual Studio. Goto Visual Studio Command prompt and type WCFTestClient

Comment: It says WCFTestClient is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: can you try with WCFstorm? http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx

Comment: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` (either from `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` or from the `<serviceDebug>` configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50810/discussion-between-dhinesh-and-sajeetharan)

Comment: @Sajeetharan When I try to debug this one, Null Parameters are received in `public int ValidateUsers(string username, string password)` in **WCF service - LoginService.cvs.cs**. Both Username and Password are null.

Comment: are the values being passed from UI? try with httpfox

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes The values are passed from UI but I can see it in **XAML.CS** part and When It calls `ValidateUsers` from **LoginService.cvs.cs** it shows null

Answer (score 1):

I assume your service is working correctly,

```
       MyLoginService.LoginServiceClient LoginClient=  new MyLoginService.LoginServiceClient();
           {
            LoginClient.ValidateUsersCompleted  += (a, ae) =>
            {
               if(ae.Error == null)
               {
               if(ae.Result != null)
               {
                if(ae.Result == 1)
                    {
                     MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully");
                    }
                    else if (ae.Result <= 0)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
                    }
                }
              }
              else
              {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error occured from service");
              } 
            };
            LoginClient.ValidateUsers(uname.Text, pass.Password);
        }
```

Comment: This how you call service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use breakpoints inside LoginService service for example in

```
   count = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

to see if its returning null,something or nothing to see if perhaps its a error in connecting to db,so I would suggest using a try catch statement like this

```
   try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                string sql = "SELECT Count(comment.Topic_Id) FROM comment inner join topic on(comment.Topic_Id=topic.id) group by topic.id limit " + start + ",10";
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    numberOfcomments[i] = rdr.GetInt16(0);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numberOfcomments;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        return ex.Message;
    }
```

constr is my string connection, in the ex.Message you would be able to see a string stating any error that would have occured,hope this help.